# i am trying to overload an operator<<

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, operator-overloading, virtual

basically what my problem is:
i have a base class and a derived class.
i need to call the operator<< on the derived class but it keeps calling the base class because in the main it was created as Order* order 
Order is the static type but it gets changed to 
order= new SpecialOrder;

so now i need it to call the derived class

thanks alot in advance :D

```
//SpecialOrder.h
#include"Order.h"
class SpecialOrder : public Order// derived class
{
  char* string;
  public:
   SpecialOrder();
   SpecialOrder(const ISBN& isbn, const char* instr);
   SpecialOrder(const SpecialOrder& source);
   bool add(istream& is);
   void display(ostream& os) const;
   SpecialOrder& operator=(const SpecialOrder& source);
   ~SpecialOrder();

};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, SpecialOrder obj);

//Order.h
#include "ISBN.h"
class Order // base class
{
  int ordered;
  int delivered;
  ISBN isbn;
  public:
  Order();
  Order(const ISBN& isbn);
  bool has(const ISBN& isbn) const;
  int outstanding() const;
  virtual bool add(istream& is);
  bool add(int n);
  bool receive(istream& is);
  void display(ostream& os) const;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Order obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do directly what you seek.  But you can have a virtual print() member in each of the classes, and have operator << ( stream & os, Order obj ) call obj's print() method.

Declare print() as

```
virtual ostream &print( ostream &s ) const;
```

within each of the classes.

Then

```
inline ostream & operator << ( ostream &os, const Order &obj )
    {
    return obj.print( os );
    }
```

(and you don't need a separate operator<< for the child class).

Comment: i have a display method in each class that prints out what i need it to.
it doesn't work tho it says that it can't find the function that is called the operator<<(ostream& os , Order);

Comment: 1. `display` should return an `ostream &`.
2. I see that you have declared an `operator << (ostream &s, Order )`.  I don't see anywhere that you've implemented it.
3. `display` should be virtual.